# What does 金一封はもらった means?

Tags: meaning, translation, words, manga, sentence

[image: s]

The source is from the manga Blue Period. For further context, students were split into teams to make curry, and whichever wins will get money for prize.

Comment: Is your question more about the meaning of 金一封 (since you write "whichever wins will get *money for prize*" so it appears to me that you already know what it means), or more about the meaning/usage of the past tense もらっ**た** ? If that's the latter then your question should be a duplicate of [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/73852/9831) and [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/85795/9831).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has a slight typo that is hard to see -- you've used ー, Unicode codepoint 30FC, the 長音符【ちょうおんぷ】 or 伸ばし【のばし】 mark used to indicate a long vowel.  In vertical text, this is always a vertical line, so we can tell that the correct character instead is 一【いち】, Unicode codepoint 4E00, the kanji meaning "one", which is always a horizontal line, even in vertical text.  In horizontal text, these two might look identical, depending on font, but copy-pasting these into online dictionaries will give you very different results.

In your manga text, we have the word:

- [金一封【きんいっぷう】](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E9%87%91%E4%B8%80%E5%B0%81) (literally "money one envelope", i.e. an envelope of money)

(Links go to the relevant entry in the Weblio E-J / J-E free online dictionary.)

In other words, someone got an envelope with money in it, probably a traditional gift looking a bit like this:

[image: Traditional Japanese "kinpū" or gift-money envelope]

Comment: [金一封]{きんいっぷう} is the word here.

Comment: @aguijonazo: Ha!  Never even occurred to me that that would be a single integral term.  Thank you!  I'll update my post.

Comment: `someone got an envelope with money in it` -- ん？まだもらってないです。その「もらっ**た** 」は、「優勝賞金はもらっ**た**も同然だ」「(うちのチームは)優勝し**た**も同然だ」って意味です。ところでその封筒は結婚祝用だから普通はこんなやつ→https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=金一封%E3%80%80賞金&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjAnIjH1aLxAhURzIsBHUNGCLAQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=金一封%E3%80%80賞金&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzoCCAA6BggAEAQQGFCVxQFYodMBYNDXAWgAcAB4AYAB5AOIAeARkgEJMC41LjEuMS4ymAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=11jNYIDVLZGYr7wPw4yhgAs&bih=694&biw=1517

Comment: (cont.) この「た」です：https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/73852/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/85795/9831